# How can I use lead() function which returns the value of two rows forward such that the second last and last row value do not return null?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I use lead() function which returns the value of two rows forward such that the second last and last row value do not return null?

```
lead(column name,2)over(order by x)
```

The above code gives null value for the second last and last row because the table ends.

In short, I want the code logic to continue from the first row after reaching the last row.

Comment: You mean you want it to wrap around?

Comment: Other than not returning NULL, what's the use case for wrapping around to the beginning?

Comment: @Barmar yes I want to wrap around

Comment: @Barmar I have a column of event date values which are offset by 2 rows and I want to compare them side by side and then calculate the difference.

Comment: There's an optional 3rd argument that specifies the default to return instead of `NULL`, but there doesn't seem to be any way to make it wrap around to the beginning.

Comment: I understand why you're offsetting, but aren't you already comparing row 1 to row 3? Why do you also need to compare row N-1 to row 1 and row N to row 2?

Comment: @Barmar, what can I say, we have to deal with all sorts of business requirements.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to create a temporary table where the first two rows are duplicated at the end.

Comment: The optional *default* value can be any expression, you could use a subquery to provide your default value; if you posted a proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) someone might be able to help more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming none of your actual values are null, you can make it wrap with coalesce and a conditional nth_value:

```
select
    name,
    coalesce(
        lead(name,2) over w,
        if(
            lead(name,1) over w is null,
            nth_value(name,2) over w,
            nth_value(name,1) over w
        )
    ) name_plus_2
from foo
window w as (order by id)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=edf735d4599e768332d92e6b8ae961d3)

If you need to do something particular when there are fewer than 3 records, you might need to make adjustments for that.

Comment: Absolutely stunning! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This won't look pretty but here is an alternative.

```
with cte as 

((select row_number() over (order by name asc) as id, name from t) union all
 (select count(*) over()+1, name from t order by name asc limit 1) union all
 (select count(*) over()+2, name from t order by name asc limit 1 offset 1))

,cte2 as

(select *, lead(name,2) over (order by id) as name2
from cte)

select *
from cte2
where id in (select id from t);
```